# PWA with Codeigniter Multilingual

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to develop PWA with codeigniter multilingual. We have placed the **manifest.json** and **service-worker.js** in the root path with **index.php**.

I believe CodeIgniter is searching the service worker in another path. The multilingual redirection is affecting it?

> Error: No matching service worker detected. you may need to reload the page

```
Manifest.json
    {
      "name": "Project",
      "short_name": "Project",
      "theme_color": "#359daf",
      2background_color": "#359DAF",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/img/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

Register service worker

```
var url = window.location.href;
var swLocation = '/sw.js';

var swReg;

if ( navigator.serviceWorker ) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {

        navigator.serviceWorker.register( swLocation ).then( function(reg){

            swReg = reg;
            swReg.pushManager.getSubscription();
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the correct file name for your Service Worker?  **service-worker.js** or **sw.js**

If file name is **service-worker.js**, so You have to call the correct name

```
var swLocation = '/service-worker.js';
```